# Passing current time to Mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've run into problem. I made field in my Mongoose schema with type "Date":

```
...
timeOfPassingQuestion: Date,
...
```

Now, I want to pass current time in hours, minutes, seconds and miliseconds and save it into that field. How should I format my Node variable so I can pass it without errors?

Edit: Also, I forgot to say that I wanna later see how much time user spent answering question by subtracting current time and time that I pulled from DB, *timeOfPassingQuestion* field.

Comment: Have you tried using the `Date` constructor as `const model = new Model({ timeOfPassingQuestion: new Date() }); model.save()`?

Comment: I didn't, but that's not what I'm looking for. I am looking for a way to format my Node variable so I can pass it to Date field in MongoDB using Mongoose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the syntax to create a schema that supports a date field:

```
// Schema
{ //...
  someDate: Date,
}

// date object that you can use whenever you decide to set it
var dateObj = new Date();
```

This will create a JavaScript date object that you can then pass into your Mongoose object for the date field.

Or, if you will always want it on creation, put it directly in your mongoose schema

```
{  //...
   createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
}
```

In order to compare the time in the future, I suggest you use moment.js, then you can query the time difference like so:

`moment(Model.createdDate).fromNow();`

Sources:

[Mongoose Schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

[Moment.js fromNow](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)

Comment: Thank you! Problem is that I cannot give that field default value of now because I don't need time when document is created, and I use that field multiple times across application. Thank you on rest of your answer! I'm gonna flag it as solution once I test it out! :)

Comment: @Slay29, Does the updated answer solve your problem?

Comment: I have one more question. Moment.js fromNow function is not calculating milliseconds. Do you know how can I get milliseconds difference. I'm storing time in DB with ms precision, so that's not problem.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ you're looking for Fractional second

Comment: First, I'm sorry for bothering you this much, but I didn't quite get this one. moment(timeFromDb).fromNow(); is returning me just seconds (and not exact seconds, it is returning me "couple of seconds"). What I wanted is that I can see how much minutes:milliseconds difference there is between date from my db and current, new Date.

Comment: Moment is a complex library, I really suggest you take the time to read this: https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/

Comment: Warning: while doing `moment(Model.createdDate).fromNow();` you are comparing the DB datetime with your Server datetime

Comment: @Crisboot, is that a question?

Comment: Nope, it's a fact. Your Answer asumes the nodejs server and the db are the same by suggesting usage of moment. Date time comparison between server and db can result in inexact time differences.